# Apache kafka message dispatching and balance loading

Tags: multithreading, message-queue, publish-subscribe, apache-kafka

I'm just started with Apache Kafka and really try to figure out, how could I design my system to use it in proper manner.

I'm building system which process data and actually my chunk of data is a task (object), that need to be processed. And object knows how it could be processed, so that's not a problem.

My system is actually a splited into 3 main component: Publisher (code which spown tasks), transport - actually kafka, and set of Consumers - it's actually workers who just pull data from the queue, process it somehow. It's important to note, that Consumer could be a publisher itself, if it's task need 2 step computation (Consumer just create tasks and send it back to transport)

So we could start with idea that I have 3 server: 1 single root publisher (kafka server also running there) and 2 consumers servers which actually handle the tasks. Data workflow is like that: Publisher create task, put it to transposrt, than one of consumers take this task from the queue and handle it. And it will be nice if each consumer will be handle the same ammount of tasks as the others (so workload spread eqauly between consumers).

Which kafka configuration pattern I need to use for that case? Does kafka have some message balancing features or I need to create 2 partitions and each consumer will be only binded to single partitions and could consume data only from this partition?

Answer (score 2):

In kafka number of partitions roughly translates to the parallelism of the system.

General tip is create more partitions per topic (eg. 10) and while creating the consumer specify the number of consumer threads corresponding to the number of partitions.

In the [High-level consumer API](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#highlevelconsumerapi) while creating the consumer you can provide the number of streams(threads) to create per topic. Assume that you create 10 partitions and you run the consumer process from a single machine, you can give topicCount as 10. If you run the consumer process from 2 servers you could specify the topicCount as 5.

Please refer to this [link](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html)

`The createMessageStreams call registers the consumer for the topic, which results in rebalancing the consumer/broker assignment. The API encourages creating many topic streams in a single call in order to minimize this rebalancing.`

Also you can dynamically increased the number of partitions using `kafka-add-partitions.sh` command under kafka/bin. After increasing the partitions you can restart the consumer process with increased topicCount

Also while producing you should use the [KeyedMessage](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerapi) class based on some random key within your message object so that the messages are evenly distributed across the different partitions

Comment: Where do i define topicCount ?

Comment: In the createMessageStreams method, give the topic -> topicCount as a Map. e.g.Map(topic1 -> 10). See the link http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#highlevelconsumerapi